# Translate := from MySQL to SQL Server 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I had several troubles when translating a stored procedure from MySQL to SQL Server 2014 with the assign operator `:=`.

What solution is suggested?

Comment: Well, `=` comes to mind.  You should edit the question and show the code you are trying to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value

You can use `=` in your T-SQL script instead.